# calculating the limit $\lim_{n\to ∞} (n+1)\int_{0}^1 x^nln(1+x)dx$

Tags: integration, limits, limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim_{n\to ∞} (n+1)\int_{0}^1 x^nln(1+x)dx$$

there are four options 
(A) 0 (B) ln 2 (C) ln 3 (D) ∞.

my answer is '0' . is that correct ?

Comment: It is not but, if you don't show your work, how do you want we explain ?

Comment: Use integration by parts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints:

- With a basic integration by parts, you get $(n+1)\int_0^1 x^n \ln(1+x)dx = \ln 2 - \int_0^1 \frac{x^{n+1}}{1+x}dx$.
- for $0<x<1$, $0 < \frac{x^{n+1}}{1+x} < x^{n+1}$

What do you think now?

Comment: so the term in right side converges to zero ? (taking integral in both sides in the inequality you have written )

Comment: Yep - but rather than guessing, I'd recommend to find the theorems in your books that will make you certain of the answer

Comment: well, i am finding a good book  where i can get topics related to this type of convergence. and i didn't guess . proceeded in a very confusing way. that was quite lengthy , so i didn't write that here. . anyway,  you can suggest a good book on the topics related to series sequence , limit that has similar kind of problems and has discussed the  solving techniques lucidly ,. . thanks.

Comment: Try using integral as reimann sum.

Comment: @ArnobShamanta: I think this stuff should be in any Integration 101 course/book, but you can have a look at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral#Inequalities) (second bullet point under "Inequalities")